# Folder wise Nginx Configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I had a website running on apache and I had .htaccess in each modules folder to make them seo friendly url, e.g.

/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/MODULE1/.htaccess
/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/MODULE2/.htaccess
/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/MODULE3/.htaccess

I had below code in each .htaccess files

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^(.*/[^\./]*[^/])$ /$1/
        RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/_-]*)$ ./index.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Now, I changed the server to Nginx and I included below code in "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

> include /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/*/nginx.conf;

Now my question is that what to put in nginx.conf file to achieve the objective as it was with .htaccess?

I have below code in "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

```
http { 
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 64; 
 include /etc/nginx/mime.types; 
 default_type    application/octet-stream; 
 log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]    "$request" ' '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ' '"$http_user_agent"   "$http_x_forwarded_for"'; 
 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main; 
 sendfile on;   
 keepalive_timeout 65; 
 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; 

 include    /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/*/nginx.conf; 

}
```

I have below code in "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/MODULE1/nginx.conf"

```
location / {
 if (-d $request_filename){
 set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
 }
 if ($rule_0 = "1"){
 rewrite ^/(.*/[^./]*[^/])$ /$1/;
 }
  rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)$ /./index.php last;
}
```

I tried different codes in "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/*/nginx.conf" and getting these kinds of errors

> nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/MODULE1/nginx.conf:1

Answer (score 0):

Is this your complete nginx.conf?

It looks like your `server` block isn't inside the `http` block, which [it should be](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server).

Comment: No, it is not complete code, I only added additional code in this file "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/MODULE1/nginx.conf;" to achieve seo friend urls.

Comment: According to your error, the problem is at the file `/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/MODULE1/nginx.conf` on line number 1. It would help if you shared the entire contents of that file and the lines where you're including that file in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. You can replace SEO / private data with sample data values if you want.

Comment: http {
server_names_hash_bucket_size   64;


    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/*/nginx.conf;
}

Comment: you can see the last line "include /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/modules/*/nginx.conf;"   and in "*/nginx.conf" files I have this code,
server {

  location / {
    if (-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }
    if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/(.*/[^./]*[^/])$ /$1/;
    }
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]*)$ /./index.php last;
  }
}

Comment: Can you please edit your question with these rules as its difficult to go through the configuration in a comment which is unformatted.

Comment: Did you change your configuration? Now it looks like your location block isn't inside your server block, which it should be. It would help if you provided the entire contents of your configuration files than just parts of it.